# How to move an Object to a specific location with a Button in Unity?

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, button

I'm new to Unity and am currently using Unity2D. What I want to do is that when a button is pressed an object moves and goes to a specific location. Currently I'm using:

```
public class MoveCard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 20f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Vector2 pos = new Vector2(5,1);

    void Update(){

    }

void CardMovement(){
    rb.MovePosition(pos * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I want the function CardMovement to initiate when I press a button, but it's not showing up in the Button Inspector and I don't know how to reference a Rigidbody2D in a button. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the inspector in the buttons 'OnClickEvent' menu, click the plus button, drop in the object that contains 'MoveCard' component. In the drop box on the right find the method 'CardMovement'. Just a note in your current code you have it set up so if you press the button it will move only one frame's worth of movement. You could change to something like this:

```
public class MoveCard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 20f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Vector2 pos = new Vector2(5,1);
    public bool moving = false;

    void Update(){
    if (moving) {
    rb.MovePosition(pos * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    }

void CardMovement(){
    moving = true;
    }
}
```

edit (still not a bad idea):

```
//..
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (moving) {
    rb.MovePosition(pos * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
//..
```

edit edit: set isKinematic to true on the rigidbody

Comment: I did as you said but it still moves there in one frame and then continues to shake a little bit.

Comment: try lowering the speed

Comment: i edited the code try in the fixed update and see if it works, remove update

Comment: Is there some other value changed on the RigidBody because mine still just snaps there? Edit: Ok it doesn't exactly snap but moves there really really fast but speed is on 1f. Also, it seems like it moves to a different location than what I put in the Vector2.

Comment: i think it moves in local position, so to where this object is in local space (in relation to its parent), not world space, and you can tweak the speed to 0.1f or use decimals if needed

Answer (score 0):

The function your button is calling should be public.

```
public void CardMovement(){
rb.MovePosition(pos * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

}

After you change it, assign again the object that has the script and try.

Comment: It worked but the object just jumps there while I want it to move to that position.

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is make a function in a script and apply that script to a game object. after making that create the button and click on the add function button to the button and drag the gameobject into the open section. afterwards chose the function from the listed scripts you added and have it call the move object script or whatever you called it.